# Redeclaration of variable

Tags: c++, arduino

When I run `Setup()` I expect to see a 't' in my console, followed by multiple 'x' characters. However it returns just multiple 't' chars. It's like my retrn never gets overwrited. Please see codesample below:

```
class Returner
{
    public:
        Returner(){}

        char test()
        {
        }
};

class TReturner: public Returner
{
    public:
        TReturner(){}

        char test()
        {
            return 't';
        }
};

class XReturner: public Returner
{
    public:
        XReturner(){}

        char test()
        {
            return 'x';
        }
};

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    TReturner t = TReturner();
    Returner * retrn = &t;

    while(1)
    {
        Serial.print( retrn.test());

        XReturner x = XReturner();
        retrn = &x;

        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code. First of all, the base class `char test()` should be virtual. You are also not returning any value from this function, where are you specified return type as `char`. Next, statements like `XReturner x = XReturner();` are tottaly unnecessary. You can simply do ` XReturner x;`. I suggest you to read a good C++ book before proceeding further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't 100% explain that behaviour - I'd expect you wouldn't get any characters printed as it'd be using Returner::test - but if you're overriding a function in C++ you need to declare it virtual in the base class:

```
class Returner 
{
  public:   
    Returner(){}
    virtual char test()
    {    
    }
};
```

Without test being virtual, the line

```
Serial.print( retrn.test() );
```

(don't you mean `retrn->test()`?) will just pick one implementation of `test` and use it always. As above I'd expect this to be the empty `Returner::test()`. You may also either need to make Returner::test abstract

```
    virtual char test() = 0;
```

or return some value if you're leaving it with a function body.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot "virtual" indeed. And ofcourse I also meant "retrn->test()"  ;)

Answer (score 0):

setup() will be called once by the bootloader. (do not create an infinite loop inside of it)
You should define a loop() function, it too will be called by the bootloader an 'infinite' number of times.